# I am trying to get a macro to display information in ascending order in a report

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure what is going wrong with this, it wont work for some reason! Any ideas? I just want to take what is pasted in and make sure that it is in ascending order least to greatest by number.

```
'Range("A:N").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
    'xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    'DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that you are sorting the `entire column` and not defining the end of the data range.

See below:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed

With ws

    Dim lRow as Long
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A1:N" & lRow).Sort Key1:=.Range("A1:A" & lRow), _ 
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, _ 
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _ 
        DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

End With
```

If you have XL 2007 or greater, this may be the way to go:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed

With ws

    Dim lRow as Long
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Sort

        With .SortFields

            .Clear
            .Add Key:=.Range("A1:A" & lRow), SortOn:=xlValues, _
                 Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With

        .SetRange .Range("A1:N" & lRow)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

   End With

End With
```

Comment: Wow...I feel foolish, ha! Unreal. Thank you again.